# How to append an item to a dictionary in a list?

Tags: python, dictionary, input, data-structures, append

Hello I a developing a text based game and I'm struggling with the drop command ; the way it works is you write "D *name of the item*" then it checks if the item is actually in the inventory and if it is, it puts it in a variable, deletes it from the inventory and I want it to append to the content indice of a room (a dictionary) and that dictionary is in a list, and I can't append to it. 
this is the code(some of it):

```
room = []
room.append({'number': 1, 'content': ""})
roomnumber = 1
inv = ["sword"]
command = input(": ")
first_letter = command(0)

if first_letter == "D":
   item = command.split(" ", 2)
   item.remove("D")
   for i in range(0, len(inv):
      inv.pop(i)
#this doesn't work
`     room[roomnumber]['content'].append(item[0])`
      item.pop(0)
```

After I have entered: "D sword", it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/antony/PycharmProjects/TextBased/Main.py", line 54, in <module>
room[roomnumber]['content'].append(item[0])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I don't get it, please help !

Comment: see all of my comments and corrections of your code added as comments inside your code, inside my answer. The main issue was that you applied a list method (append()) onto a dictionary object.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a room to be able to contain more than one thing?  If so, make your `content` field a list rather than a string:

```
room.append({'number': 1, 'content': []})
```

Now you can `append` any number of things to the `content`.

Answer (score 0):

```
room = []
room.append({'number': 1, 'content': ""})
## room = [{'number': 1, 'content': ""}]

roomnumber = 1
## you should actually change this to 0. Otherwise you will get an "index out
## of range" error (see comment below)

inv = ["sword"]
command = input(": ")
first_letter = command(0)

if first_letter == "D":
   item = command.split(" ", 2)
## why are you adding a max split here??

   item.remove("D")
   for i in range(0, len(inv)):
## equals for i in range(0, 5):, so iterates 0,1,2,3,4
## you forgot to add a closing bracket for the range

      inv.pop(i)
## what are you trying to do here? This looks strange to me, given that after each
## pop, the value of your inv will be shortened..?

#this doesn't work
      room[roomnumber]['content'].append(item[0])
## this does not work because your room list only contains one element, a 
## dictionary, at index position 0. Probably THIS is your biggest issue here. 
## Second, you're trying to change the value of 'content'. To change the value of a
## dictionarie's key, you need to use "=", and not ".append", as ".append" is used
## to append an element at the end of a list, to a list, and not to a dictionary. 
## So, use room[roomnumber]['content'] = item[0] 
      item.pop(0)
```

From what I understood, you want to add a content, in function of the roomnumber, to the content value of the dictionary of the corresponding room number. In this case, your whole syntax is wrong, and you must rather use:

```
room = []
room.append({1:""})

## and then, after the rest of the code:

room[roomnumber-1][roomnumber] = item[0]
```

or, even simpler, given that the simultaneous use of lists and dictionaries is actually obsolete here

```
## initiate one dictionary, containing all the rooms in key = roomnumber
## value = content pairs
rooms = {}

## the syntax to add a new room number with a new content into the dictionary
## would then simply be: rooms[number] = content, e.g.:
rooms[1] = ""

## to then set the value of the content for a given roomnumber, you simply use
rooms[roomnumber] = item[0]
```

I recommend you to learn about the basic differences in between lists and dictionaries in python, you seem to lack some basic understanding of how elements of lists and dictionaries are accessed / modified (no offense of course)

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks a lot guys :), I just wanted to say that the reason that some things are a bit weird is because that is only about 20 % of the code ( there are more rooms for example witch is why I needed to use dictionaries in a list) and my room number does start with 0 in my actual code :), the pop is to remove the item from the inventory (because this is the drop command) and I remove it from the item variable just to be safe that it doesn't cause any unwanted bugs. and otherwise, yes the content WAS supposed to be a list, I forgot, thanks for pointing it out and the for loop is actually closed it ( I was just in a bit of a rush when I wrote this ). Anyway, thanks everyone :)

Comment: No worries :) I'd in that case however still use the last proposition of my answer, i e use just one global dictionary and define room / contents via room[roomnumber] = content. So much easier in terms of the structure, which makes any of your operations much less prone to errors :)

Comment: Oh and please accept the answers which suit for you, such that we also get sth in return for our help 